# Running function once inside node stream pipe chain

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm using `vinyl-fs` to write a simple pipeline that loads markdown files, converts them to HTML, and saves them to disk. This is all working.

However, in the middle of my `pipe()` chain, I want to perform an asynchronous task that should just be done **once** for all my files. My current problem relates to loading a file (and it's important that file is loaded in the middle of the chain), but it's a problem I find myself stumbling upon all the time.

To solve this problem, I have started to do this:

```
vfs.src(*.md).pipe(function() {

  var loaded = false;

  return through2.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
    if(!loaded) {
      fs.readFile('myfile', function(err, data) {
        // use data for something
        loaded = true;
        cb(null, file);
      }
    } else {
      // passthrough
      cb(null, file);
    }
  });
}
```

This feels a bit silly. Am I approaching this all wrong, or is this actually an okay thing to do?

Comment: Without the bigger picture, it seems ok but you'll have to declare `loaded` globally or it will never work.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a way to use pause() and resume() for this instead of using the through2.obj function and the boolean counter?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a ton of articles about Node streams, it seems that the best implementation for this is to listen to the streams `finish` event, and then create a new stream based on the files from the former stream. This allows me to do exactly what I want: stream files through the pipeline until a point where I need to access the array of files for some task, and then continue the pipeline stream afterwards.

Here's what that looks like:

```
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');
var through = require('through2');

// array for storing file objects
var files = [];

// start the stream
var firstStream = vfs.src("*.jpg")

  // pipe it through a function that saves each file to the array
  .pipe(through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
    files.push(file);
    console.log('1: ', path.basename(file.path));
    cb(null, file);
  }))

  // when this stream is done
  .on('finish', function() {

    console.log('FINISH');

    // files will now be full of all files from stream
    // and you can do whatever you want with them.        

    // create a new stream
    var secondStream = through.obj();

    // write the files to the new stream
    files.each(function(file) {
      secondStream.write(file);
    });

    // end the stream to make sure the finish
    // event triggers
    secondStream.end();

    // now continue piping
    secondStream.pipe(through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
      console.log('2: ', path.basename(file.path));
      cb(null, file)
    }))
    .pipe(vfs.dest("tmp"));
  });
```

In this scenario, I have 5 JPG images next to my scripts, and the `console.log` will say

```
1:  IMG_1.JPG
1:  IMG_2.JPG
1:  IMG_3.JPG
1:  IMG_4.JPG
1:  IMG_5.JPG
FINISH
2:  IMG_1.JPG
2:  IMG_2.JPG
2:  IMG_3.JPG
2:  IMG_4.JPG
2:  IMG_5.JPG
```